# Resize SVG component to fit parent

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

I'm having some trouble scaling an svg component to fit it's parent container. The code below results in the svg being stretched to 100% of the window height and 50% of the window with instead of basing it off the container which it's in. Where am I going wrong?

Style:

```
.mapFrame {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: fill;
    background-color:blue;
}

.mapFrame img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.mapFrame svg {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:green;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

React component:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import "./Map.css"

const Map = (props) => {
    const [map, setmap] = useState(props.mapUrl);

    return (
        <div className="mapFrame">
            <img src={map} />
            <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <path d="M0 0 L100 0 L50 100 Z" />
            </svg>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Map
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrJJ6.png)

Comment: You can use AutoSizer component and pass width and height explicitly to the svg element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you set the container to relative?

Otherwise, it will not act as referring container for any child dimensions.

```css
.mapFrame {
    position: relative; /* this */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: fill;
    background-color:blue;
}
```